# Get custom attribute value for countdown timer (timer shows NaN)

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Can't assign the end date to the variable for the timer to work. As a result, I get NaN
Can you please tell me what is the mistake?

```js
var countDownDate = new Date($("countdown").data("datetime")).getTime();

function ctd() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  countdown = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
  countdown[0].innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    countdown.innerHTML = "Item expired!";
  }
}
ctd();
var x = setInterval(ctd, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<time class="countdown" datetime="2020-11-22T16:20:22+00:00"></time>
```

Comment: Welcome!
Please consider adding `jquery` and/or any other relevant tags to the question.
Thank you.
By the way - your snippet doesn't work because it's sandboxed - edit it and enable jquery (as far as I know, you cannot load external libraries any other way).
Good luck!
Also, you are calling ctd before x is defined - not sure how it affects the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You repeat some of the time calculations every second, better use some const instead:

```js
const eCountDown = document.querySelector('.countdown')
  ,   one_Sec    = 1000
  ,   one_Min    = one_Sec * 60
  ,   one_Hour   = one_Min * 60 
  ,   one_Day    = one_Hour * 24
  ;
var countDownDate = new Date(eCountDown.dateTime).getTime()
  ;
function ctd()
  {
  let now      = new Date().getTime()
    , distance = countDownDate - now
    , days     = Math.floor(distance / one_Day)
    , hours    = Math.floor((distance % one_Day)  / one_Hour)
    , minutes  = Math.floor((distance % one_Hour) / one_Min)
    , seconds  = Math.floor((distance % one_Min)  / one_Sec)
    ;
  eCountDown.textContent = days + 'd ' 
                         + hours + 'h ' 
                         + minutes + 'm ' 
                         + seconds + 's '
                         ;
  if (distance < 0)
    {
    clearInterval(timerIntv)
    countdown.textContent = 'Item expired!'
    }
  }
ctd()
var timerIntv = setInterval(ctd, 1000)
```

```html
<time class="countdown" datetime="2020-11-22T16:20:22+00:00"></time>
```

Comment: A matter of preference, but I can't help myself from not saying: very difficult to look at your coding style - the commas at the beginning of lines after `var`, `{` in the next line, no indentation withing `{}`...  But, hey - it works...

Comment: @iAmOren I am using WhiteSmith style coding .., and I put the commas before to be sure to see them and not to forget them at the end of the line.

Comment: Yeah, didn't remember the name - still, looks horrible to me and - I rarely see code indented/styled this way...
I can't think of a time I forgot a comma...: if there are more variables, there are commas - the end is with a semi-colon... - If I'm coding to show parts of code, I might even put the semi-colon at a new line all by itself, but, aligned with the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.countdown` to get a class. You were missing the dot (.)

Also you should use `attr` or `prop` and not `data`. You can use `data` if you change your html property to `data-datetime`.

When in doubt, always `console.log(countDownDate)` to see what you get first.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date($(".countdown").attr("datetime"));

function ctd() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  countdown = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
  countdown[0].innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    countdown.innerHTML = "Item expired!";
  }
}
ctd();
var x = setInterval(ctd, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<time class="countdown" datetime="2020-11-22T16:20:22+00:00"></time>
```